# co. corp. inc. regular expression

Tags: java, regex

This is my first time working with regular expressions and I've been trying to get a regular expression working that would match the following:

- apple
- apple inc.
- apple co.
- apple corp.

but would not match:

- inc. apple
- co. apple
- apple co. inc.
- apple corp. inc.
- apple inc. corp.
- and so on...

This is what I got so far (apple)\s(inc|corp|co).$

Think you could help :)

EDIT: It needs to work in Java. Does java have it's own syntax for Regular Expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
^apple(?:\s(?:inc|co|corp)\.)?$
```

Note that if you want your regexp to be case insensitive, you either have to pass the `CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag when constructing the pattern or add `(?i)` to the pattern.

Comment: An alternate, and silly, way to get case insensitivity is to say [Aa][pP][pP][lL][eE], etc.

Comment: Agreed - it's possible, and it's silly. :-) Still, a nice hack if you're in a context where you can't pass the case insensitive option.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
^apple\s?(inc|corp|co)?\.?$
```

Be careful with periods (.) as they are wildcards ( put a backslash in front of them).

? means not required

^ means beginning of the line

$ means end of the line

Look here for a more complete explanation: http://www.anaesthetist.com/mnm/perl/Findex.htm

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(?<!(?:inc|co|corp)\.\s)apple(?:\s(?:inc|co|corp)\.)?
```

It uses a negative lookbehind `(?<!  )` to prevent the prefixes, plus non-capturing groups `(?:  )` to discard unnecessary backreferences.

The `.` has been escaped to `\.` since it is otherwise a regex symbol meaning "any character".

The `$` you used means end of line - so unless you only want this to match at the end of your string, you don't want it.
However, if you *are* searching specifically for the whole string being "apple inc." (etc) then you can keep the $ and replace the negative lookbehind with `^` to simplify the expression to:

```
^apple(?:\s(?:inc|co|corp)\.)?$
```